# How to start the task and cancel it?

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, task

I want to detect the `SerialPort` automaticlly. So I have five comboboxs to select the parameters of `SerialPort` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="BaudRate"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_BaudRate" SelectedIndex="2">
    <ComboBoxItem>9600</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>14400</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>19200</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>38400</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>56000</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>115200</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock Text="DataBit"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_DataBit" SelectedIndex="0" >
    <ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>7</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock Text="Parity" />
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Parity" SelectedIndex="0" >
    <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Odd</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Even</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock Text="StopBit" />
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_StopBit" SelectedIndex="0" >
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Button x:Name="btn_Auto_Detect" Click="btn_Find_Click" />
```

When I click the `btn_Auto_Detect` I want to set different parameters of these combobox to the `try_Port` and try to connect my device by sending data using the `try_Port`. The Problem is this action may take a few minutes. So I may cancel this task durning this time.

```
public bool cancelFlag = false;
private void btn_Find_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    if(cancelFlag)
    {
        cancelFlag = false;
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        Hint("Searching Canceled!");
    }
    else
    {
        cancelFlag = true;
        Hint("Start Searching...");
    }

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Matching_Process_Thread();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }, token).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
           ...

        }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}


public static SerialPort try_port = new SerialPort();
private void Matching_Process_Thread()
{
    int tryNumber = 0;
    //Loop searching the portname, baudrate, databit, parity, stopbit
    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox_Port.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        try_port.PortName = comboBox_Port.Items[i].ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < comboBox_BaudRate.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < comboBox_DataBit.Items.Count; k++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < comboBox_Parity.Items.Count; m++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < comboBox_StopBit.Items.Count; n++)
                    {
                        //Here I want to update the UI                       
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action<int, int, 
                        int, int>(Update_ComboBoxs), j, k, m, n);

                        if(!try_port.isOpen){ try_port.Open(); }
                        ...
                        //if get response, return
                        //else close this try_port.close() and return;
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
   }

    private void Update_ComboBoxs(int baudrate, int databit, int parity, int stopbit)
    {
        this.comboBox_BaudRate.SelectedIndex = baudrate;
        try_port.BaudRate = int.Parse(comboBox_BaudRate.Text);

        this.comboBox_DataBit.SelectedIndex = databit;
        try_port.DataBits = int.Parse(comboBox_DataBit.Text);

        this.comboBox_Parity.SelectedIndex = parity;
        switch (parity)
        {
            case 0:
                try_port.Parity = Parity.None;
                break;
            case 1:
                try_port.Parity = Parity.Odd;
                break;
            case 2:
                try_port.Parity = Parity.Even;
                break;
            default:break;
        }

        this.comboBox_StopBit.SelectedIndex = stopbit;
        switch (stopbit)
        {
            case 0:
                try_port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                break;
            case 1:
                try_port.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
                break;
            default:break;
        }
    }
```

But this never stop the task and I dont know why!

How should I fix this or is there any better method to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why did you use the DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle and not another option?

Comment: Have you checked if Update_ComboBoxs in the Action has been finished before try_port.open() is executed? If yes, have you debugged the code? Without having tested your code it seems to me that the error has nothing to do with updating the ui from within a task.

Comment: Yes I have debugged the code, and if I put update ui code into the loop. It works fine except it takes a very long time ot finish the task.

Comment: Maybe. From Microsoft msdn: SystemIdle - Operations are processed when the system is idle. Try another priority

Comment: I changed the DispatcherPriority. It's the same.

Comment: Is there more information about the error? A line number where it fails?

Comment: Does this happen on the first time through the loop? Have you tried using a local SerialPort variable (rather than global static) & create a new instance each time round the loop - putting it in a using statement so it is correctly disposed..

Comment: So you are trying to enumerate all possible com-port settings to see which one is working? You are not closing opened serial port, so that the second iteration of the most nested `for` will `throw` exactly said message.

Comment: Another thing is accessing UI controls from non-UI thread, e.g. `comboBox_DataBit.Items` inside `for` is bad. A simple fix is to move all `for`s  and changing UI code into UI thread. Then you only need to run the long job (to open serial port with current settings, attempt to communicate and closing) inside using `async/await`, `Timer` or `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `IsCancellationRequested` property inside your loops. You check it once at the start of your task and then never again.

I'd check it right before a slower operation, and right after if there is more than one slow operation. Then return out of your function and the cancellation will work as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!